# How to open specific link on different phone localisation

Tags: android, browser, localization, hyperlink

This is the case

I am building app that will be localized via strings to many languages. There is a part of app with bunch of helpful links  but I would like to open specific link in dependence of actual phone localisation.

So in example if the app is showing in German I would like to send user to German translation of web site, but if the user is seeing app in English I would like to send that user to English translation of specific page via link to that specific translation.

I did a lot to my app looking at examples here. So If you could drop me a hint on this.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make different `string` file with your url for different Language written in that and put that String file in `values-fr , values-eng` folder.

More to know about localization go through

[this post](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

For those who do not get it form firs this is the final example

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      switch (v.getId()) { 
               case R.id.link1: 
                      Intent link1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.link1web))); 
                      startActivity(link1); 
                      break; } }
```

where link1web is my defined string in String.xml

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but how will I call that string since I am calling my links via intent in my activity?

Comment: you can get urlstring defined in String.xml like this `getResources().getString(R.string.urlstring);`

Comment: Thanks man. That line solved all my problems. For those who do not get it form firs this is the final example
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.link1:
   Intent link1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
   Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.link1web)));
   startActivity(link1);
   break;

where link1web is my defined string.